# What are Chrome's URL address bar suggestions based on?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, browser, url

I used a remote desktop device from a cloud provider that rent devices (like amazon EC2). I created the device from scratch.

When I try to use Chrome browser and start typing a website name, it auto completes it and shows a list of suggested websites. I have not visited these websites as far as I remember. Also, I delete the history.

Any idea what are these website suggestions based on? If not my history then what exactly? Is it influenced by the users of the same DNS or what?

Comment: The algorithm is unknown, but it's based on world-wide statistics mixed with your personal data.

Answer (score 1):

That would be Chrome's auto-suggestions, same as when you search something using Google.